# How do I convert a Python dictionary, with a list of values for key, so that each value in the list is in its own row

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Convert my_dict into a PySpark dataframe.  The starting dictionary looks like:

```
my_dict = {'z': 'some_string', 'y':'some_other_string', 'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]}
```

Easy enough to do in Python using `my_dict.from_dict`, but I guess this isn't Kansas no more!  Haven't found a straight way in PySpark to accomplish this.

The resulting PySpark DataFrame should be represented as:

```
'a'       'b'     'z'           'y'
 1         4  'some_string'  'some_other_string'
 2         5  'some_string'  'some_other_string'
 3         6  'some_string'  'some_other_string'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to pass data to `spark.createDataFrame`, we'll want all row lists to be the same length. We can extract the data from your dictionary in the following way:

```
n_rows = max([len(vals) if isinstance(vals, list) else 1 for vals in my_dict.values()])
# n_rows = 3

col_names = list(my_dict.keys())

data = [vals if len(vals) == n_rows else [vals]*n_rows for _,vals in my_dict.items()]
# [['some_string', 'some_string', 'some_string'],
#  ['some_other_string', 'some_other_string', 'some_other_string'],
#  [1, 2, 3],
#  [4, 5, 6]]

# transpose data
pyspark_data = list(zip(*data))

# pyspark data
# [('some_string', 'some_other_string', 1, 4),
#  ('some_string', 'some_other_string', 2, 5),
#  ('some_string', 'some_other_string', 3, 6)]
```

Then we can create the pyspark dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    pyspark_data,
    col_names
)

+-----------+-----------------+---+---+
|          z|                y|  a|  b|
+-----------+-----------------+---+---+
|some_string|some_other_string|  1|  4|
|some_string|some_other_string|  2|  5|
|some_string|some_other_string|  3|  6|
+-----------+-----------------+---+---+
```

Comment: Absolutely worked as advertised; your feedback has been greatly appreciated!  Solved!

Comment: Thanks! Glad to have helped!